# Class hierarchy problem (with generic's variance!)

Tags: c#, generics, oop, generic-variance

**The problem:**

```
class StatesChain : IState, IHasStateList {
    private TasksChain tasks = new TasksChain();

     ...

    public IList<IState> States {
        get { return _taskChain.Tasks; }
    }

    IList<ITask> IHasTasksCollection.Tasks {
        get { return _taskChain.Tasks; } <-- ERROR! You can't do this in C#!
                                             I want to return an IList<ITask> from
                                             an IList<IStates>.
    }
}
```

Assuming the `IList` returned will be read-only, I know that what I'm trying to achieve is safe (or is it not?). Is there any way I can accomplish what I'm trying? I wouldn't want to try to implement myself the `TasksChain` algorithm (again!), as it would be error prone and would lead to code duplication. Maybe I could just define an abstract Chain and then implement both `TasksChain` and `StatesChain` from there? Or maybe implementing a `Chain<T>` class?

How would you approach this situation?

**The Details:**
I have defined an `ITask` interface:

```
public interface ITask {
    bool Run();
    ITask FailureTask { get; }
}
```

and a `IState` interface that inherits from `ITask`:

```
public interface IState : ITask {
    IState FailureState { get; }
}
```

I have also defined an `IHasTasksList` interface:

```
interface IHasTasksList {
    List<Tasks> Tasks { get; }
}
```

and an `IHasStatesList`:

```
interface IHasTasksList {
    List<Tasks> States { get; }
}
```

Now, I have defined a `TasksChain`, that is a class that has some code logic that will manipulate a chain of tasks (beware that `TasksChain` is itself a kind of `ITask`!):

```
class TasksChain : ITask, IHasTasksList {
    IList<ITask> tasks = new List<ITask>();

    ...

    public List<ITask> Tasks { get { return _tasks; } }

    ...
}
```

I am implementing a `State` the following way:

```
public class State : IState {
    private readonly TaskChain _taskChain = new TaskChain();

    public State(Precondition precondition, Execution execution) {
        _taskChain.Tasks.Add(precondition);
        _taskChain.Tasks.Add(execution);
    }

    public bool Run() {
        return _taskChain.Run();
    }

    public IState FailureState {
        get { return (IState)_taskChain.Tasks[0].FailureTask; }
    }

    ITask ITask.FailureTask {
        get { return FailureState; }
    }
}
```

which, as you can see, makes use of explicit interface implementations to "hide" `FailureTask` and instead show `FailureState` property.

The problem comes from the fact that I also want to define a `StatesChain`, that inherits both from `IState` and `IHasStateList` (and that also imples `ITask` and `IHasTaskList`, implemented as explicit interfaces) and I want it to also hide `IHasTaskList`'s `Tasks` and only show `IHasStateList`'s `States`. *(What is contained in "The problem" section should really be after this, but I thought puting it first would be way more reader friendly).*

*(pff..long text)* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line where you get an error, you're trying to return `IList<IStates>` as if it was an instance of type `IList<ITask>`. This doesn't work automtaically, because the two types are different (no matter that the generic parameters are related).

In C# 3.0 or older, there is no way to achieve that automatically. C# 4.0 adds support for covariance and contravariance, which serves exactly this purpose. But as you noted, this works only when the returned collection is read-only. The `IList<T>` type doesn't guarantee that, so it isn't annotated as *covariant* in .NET 4.0.

To make this work using C# 4.0, you'll need to use *truly read-only type*, which has covariant annotation in the framework - the best option in your case is `IEnumerable<T>` (although you could define your own using the `out T` modifier).

To add more details, in C# 4.0, you can declare an interface as either covariant or contra-variant. The first case means that the compiler will allow you to perform the conversion you needed in your example (the other case is useful for write-only classes). This is done by adding explicit annotations to the interface declaration (these are already available for .NET 4.0 types). For example, the declaration of `IEnumerable<T>` has the `out` annotation meaning that it supports covariance:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable { /* ... */ }
```

Now, the compiler will allow you to write:

```
IEnumerable<IState> states = ...
IEnumerable<ITask> tasks = states;
```

Comment: Thanks by the answer. What defines what is a truly read-only type in the eyes of C#? What is the mechanism behind allowing IEnumerable<T> and not IList<T>?

Comment: It's explicit (defining `in` or `out` notation on the type parameter), not implicit. Google returns a bunch of great results for the following query: http://www.google.ch/search?q=covariant+contravariant+in+out

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is it something new to C# 4.0? Thanks

Comment: Yes, older C# versions did not allow co- and/or contravariance on anything but arrays and type references (even tough the .NET Framework runtime is said to have been supporting it since the introduction of generics V2).

Comment: I added some more details - I wasn't sure if you're already talking about C# 4.0 or not (since your question explicitly mentioned variance - which is generally quite unfamiliar concept!)

Answer (score 2):

In short, no it is not safe, since a "read-only" `IList<>` doesn't exist (contract-wise). It's only the implementation which will reject entries, but that's too late, as the call itself would require the interface type parameter to be both co- and contravariant at the same time.

You could, however, return an `IEnumerable<>` instead, which is covariant in C# 4. Since this is enough to use LINQ, that shouldn't be too much of a drawback and expresses the read-only nature better.

Comment: I've long wished that the hierarchy of `Collections.Generic` interfaces included read-only variants. Covariance is yet another reason why that would have been great. But because almost all collection interfaces are writable we can't get covariance. Gah!...

Comment: @romkyns, there are several other "missing" interfaces in the BCL, such as `IArithmetic<>` on numeric primitives (which would enable generic math operations by using the interface as type constraint), `ICharSequence` (or similar to enable any char sequence to be used for instance as `Regex` or `StringReader` source instead of a string) and so on...